# Two packages are in same folder then while importing package1 in package2 its giving error as package does not exists in java

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I'm executing this code in the command prompt. This is the first package Person1 I want to import this package in Employee package.
\\Person Package in `Person.java` file

```
package Person1;
public class Person{
public String name;
Person(String name)
{
setname(name);
}

public void setname(String name)
{
this.name=name;
}
public String getname()
{
return name;
}
}
```

\package Employee in `Employee.java` file

```
package Employee;
import Person1.*;//error:package Person1 does not exist.
class Employee
{
......
}
```

As these, both packages lie in the same folder named as `Inheritance`.Please help me out to resolve this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you write the code with a simple text editor, without a support of a IDE tool. An IDE tool (like Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea) will help you prevent such errors in the future.

I assume your files lie in the directory structure like this:

```
./Person1/Person.java
./Employee/Employee.java
```

If it is like this, then it should actually work. I assume it is not. Please check. Please provide more information about how you compile in case you still have issues.

And please note. Package names are by convention always lower case.